# C++ Direct Access To Wires

Tags: c++, led

I am wanting to create a c++ program that will power cables.Like a ethernet cable has several wires in it.How would I choose a wire and send current through it?
If anyone can explain how to send current over specific wires that would be great.I also do not want to use a library.To make it even clearer , I wish to be able to do something like this  [Video] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1enhkLZm10 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will answer your question: [I/O Ports controlled LEDs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4981/I-O-Ports-Uncensored-Controlling-LEDs-Light-Emit).

This is a code snippet from the website on how to communicate with a port:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h> // For _out
#define port 0x378 // Port Address
#define data port+0 // Data Port of the parallel cable
void main (void)
{
  _out(data, 255); // For all lights on
  _out(data, 0); // For all lights off
}
```

If you don't know how computers communicate with peripherals, and how different ports like USB(Universal Serial Bus), Serial ports, and other ports communicate and work. This guide should help you get started.[Control Physical World Through Computer (Step by Step)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43458/Control-Physical-World-Through-Computer-Step-by-St)

Comment: Thanks! The page was helpful and I found a link that explains it better.